# ImportError: No module named yaml

Tags: python, eclipse, flask, yaml, pydev

I am very new to PyDev and Python, though I have used Eclipse but I did't do much with it. So I am having some trouble with importing yaml in my Flask project.

I install yaml and I can import it from the terminal. But I can't import it when I try to run the project in the eclipse

```
import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

What is the way of importing or setting yaml library to my eclipse flask project ?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: did you set the interpreter for the project in your IDE?

Comment: nope, I didn't set up virtualenv for it. @ivan Cai

Comment: Run this from both eclipse and the commandline: `import sys; print(sys.executable)` Do you get the same result for both?

Comment: yes I check that again, my interpreter set as python2.7 @Amin Etesamian

Comment: @shuttle87 Yes you are right they are showing different paths, in terminal it shows usr/bin/python but when I did use same command in eclipse I didn't realized that I set a virtual env for another projects and I set all projects interpreters path as virtualenv's python path. I fixed it with window>preferences>pydev>interpreters>python interpreters than I set the usr/bin/python one instead of virtualenv's interpreter                            Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this from both eclipse and the commandline:

```
import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

Do you get the same result for both?

using this statements help me to understand I was using different interpreters which are located in my system. thank you @shuttle87

Comment: I've run into this with PyYAML specifically when I've got a chebang at the top of a script & I run it in a virtualenv -- if it's using my system python instead of the virtualenv python, there's confusion about how to resolve the dependency.  

In my case the fix was to remove the literal path in the #!, or to update the execution pattern to use python myScript.py

Answer (score 4):

Run below commands to install latest yaml-

```
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
tar -xvzf PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
cd PyYAML-3.12
python setup.py install
```

> ```
> Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 21 2017, 21:46:26)
> [GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> import yaml
> >>>
> ```