# ROS - ImportError: No module named yaml

Tags: yaml, ros, pyyaml

I am new to ROS and am trying to run a python script from the tutorials mentioned in ROS website(link below)
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber

When I run the command: $ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py

This error pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tarapreeth/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/talker.py", line 39, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Bool import *
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Bool.py", line 6, in <module>
    import genpy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 48, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I tried installing yaml using:
pip install pyyaml

I get this: Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.3.1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939541/importerror-no-module-named-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as there were multiple versions of python present on the system.

Solution:
`ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

You can put it in ~/.bashrc to avoid it in future